# How do I keep floated elements flopping down without using a fixed width?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am styling a series of form rows. Each row div has a fixed-width label div, and a content div that can contain any number of float: left elements.

Example markup is:

```
<div class="Row">        
    <div class="Label">Label Here</div>        
    <div class="Content">            
        <div class="Item">Short Content</div>        
    </div>        
</div>    
<div class="Row">        
    <div class="Label">Label Here</div>        
    <div class="Content">            
        <div class="Item">
            Long Content ... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id eros magna. Suspendisse eu diam nunc. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu neque massa.
        </div>                
    </div>        
</div>
```

CSS so far is:

```
.Row {
    clear: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

.Label {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

.Content {
    float: left;
}

.Content .Item {
    float: left;
}
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vVy5J/2/

This looks correct as long as the contents of the content div are not wider than the remaining width in the row. If they are, the content div 'flops' down beneath the label instead and hugs the left edge of the row div: http://screencast.com/t/Iknv98R9

I need long content divs to wrap, but still be against the top of the row and flush with the right edge of the label.

The traditional solution for this is to give the content div a fixed width. But that won't fly here because the row widths vary based on browser window size, etc. and the content div needs to stretch from the right edge of the label div to the right edge of the containing row div.

Requirements: I can alter the markup only within the row div. Contents need to be elements, so text-indent won't work for me. I need to support IE7+

Comment: Here is a notepad mockup of the end result I am trying for: http://screencast.com/t/J72UO0QKs

Comment: Another requirement I implied but did not mention: The row div needs to stretch vertically as the content div wraps, so that it is as tall as it needs to be, but no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a `position:relative;` on the Row, `position:absolute;` on the Label just to take it out of the document flow, then `margin-left:150px` on the Content (or however wide it's supposed to be).

It won't be good though if there's any chance of the Label being taller than the Content.

Comment: This is a great idea. I put it together in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVy5J/4/). Check it out and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple positioning trick. #row must be relative and content is absolute with left: 150px.

```
.Row
{
    ...
    position: relative;
}

.Content
{
    ...
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVy5J/3/)

Comment: Close, but no cigar :\ If the content div is position: absolute, it will not contribute to the row height, and so the row div will not stretch to fit, and the content will flop out over the next row: http://screencast.com/t/gPniwOSdpi